# Выделяется ли запятыми слово "крича" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Пора нам всем вместе взбираться на гору, крича, какие мы сильные духом!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно расставили запятые. *Крича* здесь — одиночное деепричастие, которое обособляется по правилам пунктуации.